# intermediate calculus between Natural and Sequent Calculus

Tags: logic, natural-deduction, sequent-calculus

So as to formalize arithmetic, Gentzen uses an intermediate calculus between the two basic calculi NK and LK. In such calculus, for example,  one can deduce $\supset$-elimination rule:  $\Delta,\Gamma \Rightarrow $  from  $\Delta \Rightarrow  \supset $  and $\Gamma \Rightarrow $.
My question is how can we obtain  the intermediate calculus from Natural deduction NK and Sequent Calculus LK?

Comment: It is simply Natural Deduction written is "sequent-style". For example, $\lor$-elim is: from $\Gamma \to A \lor B$ and $A, \Delta \to C$ and $B, \Theta \to C$, follows: $\Gamma, \Delta, \Theta \to C$.